# How to add a column which has another column value as default value in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table `emp` which has 4 columns : `emp_cd, emp_name, updated_by, update_dt`.

Now I am to add another column named as `inserted_by`.

When I insert anything in table, the value of `inserted_by` column should be set same as `updated_by`.

When I update table `update_by` column value will be updated but `inserted_by` column value should remain unchanged.

Comment: Okaaaaaay, and what is your question?

Comment: i have tried the following sql : "alter table emp add inserted_by as updated_by" . but problem is inserted _by column value is changing as i update the value of updated_by column.

Comment: For adding a col. you can simply try a alter command here. and for furthur manupulations, you haver to do it at your front end.

Comment: I don't want to use 'inserted_by' column in my insert and update queries..

Comment: I think you should have a look at *triggers*. There you can distinguish between, what to be done `AFTER INSERT` or `AFTER UPDATE`

Comment: I know this can be achieved by using `Instead of trigger`. but don't want to use triggers. if there is any other to do it...?

Comment: Write 2 queries and run them in sequence, the first one with the insert, the second one with the update.

Comment: If you already know the 'update_by' value on insert, why don't you just put the same in 'inserted_by' field?

Comment: That's what I am asking myself, too. And where and how are your records inserted/updated?

Comment: Records are updated through `powerbuilder` screens.There are a lot screens which use the same table so i can not change my insert queries every where. I want to do this at sql server side.

Comment: Then you don't have any other opportunities like triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a trigger on INSERT:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_Insert_Emp
ON [emp]
FOR INSERT
AS
Begin
    Update [emp] 
    Set inserted_by = ( Your_Values_Or_Subquery )
    from Inserted i
    Left Join emp e
    on i.emp_cd = e.emp_cd 
End
```

Take a look to AFTER INSERT too.

Comment: hi Francesco De Lisi, thanks for ur answer.. but if there is another way of doing it.. i don't want to use triggers.